# Windows 7 cannot connect to smtp... but some do

Tags: windows, windows-7, firewall

I have a weird problem. Since two days I cannot send emails using outlook.
I even cannot establish a smtp connection using telnet on 25 or 587.

So it seems Windows is blocking outgoing connections.

Ironically, some smtp connections work. I.e. GMX or Gmail.

Where should I look inside Windows to find more about this behavior?

More Details:
Windows 7 (all Updates installed)
Office 2010 (all Updates installed)

- telnet smtp.gmx.net 25 --> works
- telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 --> works
- telnet mail.monopolar.de 25 --> not working !!!

But this server is working and listening on 25 and 587. I can connect to it using my macbook. and its reachable from other windows pcs

But from one special windows notebook i cannot connect, so i think its a windows settings-bug.

And with this single notebook it doesnt work at home and in office.

Comment: What SMTP server you use? Own or some cloud-based one like hotmail, live, etc? If own, what is your SMTP loks like? Are you trying to set it up on desktop or phone? This works at home, but not in the office? A bit more details please.

Comment: No Idea? This must be a Windows Issue...